# Sum of links in one cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro that sums a lot of values from other worksheets that follow this structure:

`='[HT_CSI_S112_005001_10100_EEA2019_20100154308.xlsm]CIIU_T apr'!T15+'[HT_CSI_S112_005001_10100_EEA2019_20221084684.xlsm]CIIU_T apr'!T15 + [...]`

Considerer that I'll have more than 2 links on that cell. Also, every file is on a same directory and follows the same structure only the name is different.

But, I have no idea how to add the next conditional that should add the value of the extra links. I tried to do this for the first value:

```
destWorkbook.Sheets("CIIU_T").AutoFilterMode = False
destWorkbook.Worksheets("CIIU_T").Range("P13:R854").Copy
templateCopy.Worksheets("CIIU_T_AJUSTADO").Activate
If Not IsEmpty(Range("T13")) Then
Range("T13").Activate
**(I have no idea how to do this)**
Else
Range("T13").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
End If
```

Comment: Why you need `more than 2 links on that cell`? What's the expected result?

Comment: Linked formulas to external workbooks can be overwhelming sometimes and slow down everything. Note that everytime you change something in the sheet Excel will recalculate the links and the sum. Probably you'll need your code to loop trough each workbook, get the cell value and add it to a grandtotal variable and then paste this result.